# US Phone regex that works in IE

Tags: regex, internet-explorer-7, phone-number

I had been using the following regex for US Phone Number validation, but discovered it doesn't work in IE7.  I am aware of the lookahead issues, and was able to fix a password validation by moving the length question to the beginning, but can't figure out how to adjust the phone number one:

```
/^(?:(?:(\s*\(?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\)?\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this regex:

```
/^\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*[.-]?\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*[.-]?\s*([0-9]{4})\s*$/
```

Comment: Omega, I appreciate your prompt response.  I'm not very good with regex, so I can't confirm what you posted is exactly what I need just by looking at it.  It seems much shorter than the original - does it accomplish the exact same criteria as the original, except that it's IE7-friendly?  The orig supposedly provided: "US phone #s w/ area code; various permutations of formatting characters (parens, space, dash).  Area code optionally enclosed in parens. Rejects area codes that begin with 0 or 1 and prefixes that begin with 0. Must be 10 digits, not counting the formatting characters."

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, I left the office for the day after my last comment.  Thanks again, I'll plug it in and see what happens!